# Indent HTML inline elements with PHP Tidy

Tags: php, html, indentation, tidy

Google doesn't show me the answer to this question, how to force HTML Tidy to indent html inline elements such as (A, SPAN) the same way as it does for block elements?

Input:

```
<a href="#test"><span>Text</span></a>
```

Desired output:

```
<a href="#test">
    <span>
        Text
    </span>
</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it isn't possible, based on http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Comment: I also tried setting `'new-blocklevel-tags' => 'a,span',` in options array to see if you could force tidy to treat those specific elements as blocklevel, but no dice.

Comment: Yeah, i did so as well, but it doesn't work that way. You are right, it seems that it isn't possible. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428746/is-there-a-command-line-gnu-linux-tool-for-php-coding-standards-with-html-inl